# Controls cannot be accessed inside my function

Tags: c#, wpf

just a quick question, can you tell me why I can't access my controls like popup or textbox or the 'this' inside the function that has a comment, please check it out. I really need to know why asap. Thank you so much!

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);


        public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        public static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        public static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        public const uint VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90;
        public const uint VK_CAPITAL = 0x14;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            MouseDown += delegate { DragMove(); };
            InitializeComponent();
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        }

        public void mainForm_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }

        public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Popup1.IsOpen = false;
            timer.Stop();
        }

        public static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                if (vkCode == VK_CAPITAL)
                {
                    if (Console.CapsLock == true)
                    {
                       // I WANT TO ACCESS MY CONTROLS HERE (popup, textbox, etc... this);

                    }
                }



            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }


        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
            base.OnClosed(e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a static event to your window:

```
public static event EventHandler CapsLockEnabled;
```

Next, add a handler for this event:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    MouseDown += delegate { DragMove(); };
    InitializeComponent();
    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

    CapsLockEnabled += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("caps lock enabled"); };
}
```

Your event handler, because it's defined on an instance, has full access to all of the window's controls.

Finally, raise the event from your `HookCallback` method:

```
public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if (vkCode == VK_CAPITAL)
        {
            if (Console.CapsLock == true)
            {
                var handler = CapsLockEnabled;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(typeof(MainWindow), EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I like that much better and it appears to integrate well.  Nice one, Steven.

Comment: Hi sir Steven, thank you so much, however, the "this" in the handler gives me an error. Not valid in a static property, static method, or static initializer. something like that.

Comment: Hey sir Steve, I will mark your answer as answer. Thank you so much! I just replaced the this by whatever. Like "" string, etc.... It works. However, I can't add more stuffs in event handler. Like timer.start(); Anyway, thank you again! :)

Comment: @user3231194 Sorry about that, my own fault for typing it up without testing it first. Obviously you cannot reference `this` in a static method. Just replace `handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);` with `handler(typeof(MainWindow), EventArgs.Empty);`. I've updated the code in the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

It is a static method.  "this" and the controls belong to the instance and can't be seen inside of a static method.

With the use of those .dlls, I can't provide a bulletproof method of accessing it.  I would not advise resorting to hopes and dreams, but in the case where the MainWindow is the active window, you could do something like the following:

```
public static void StaticMainWindowMethod(string incomingMessage)
    {
        var activeWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
        if (activeWindow != null)
        {
            var mainWindow = activeWindow as MainWindow;
            if (mainWindow != null)
            {
                mainWindow.InstanceMainWindowMethod(incomingMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void InstanceMainWindowMethod(string passedFromStaticMessage)
    {
        this.MainTextBox.Text = passedFromStaticMessage;
    }
```

The idea is that you need to get the instance of the window in order to get at its properties/controls.  Depending on how your application is designed, you may be able to get at it through application level properties.  Its reliability is really up to the design of the application.

Comment: oh I see. Is there anyway I can access my controls inside a static method? plss?

Comment: Hi, thanks Mark, now I know. the .dll imports need to be static, if I remove all the static keyword in my whole program, the program won't run. I need to find a way somehow to make my popup control to popup :(((

Comment: see the edit.  not pretty or reliable, but will hopefully start you down the path of coming up with a better solution.